# Help in proving that a vector norm satisfies an axiom.

Tags: normed-spaces

I am trying to prove if the following is a vector norm:

||x|| = max{$|x_1 + x_2|, |x_2 + x_3|, |x_3 + x_1$|}    (x is vector with 3 elements)

I'm stuck proving that $||\alpha x||=|\alpha|*||x||$.

I have done the following:

$||\alpha x||=$ max{$|\alpha x_1 + \alpha x_2|, |\alpha x_2 + \alpha x_3|, |\alpha x_3 + \alpha x_1$|}

= max{$|\alpha(x_1 + x_2)|, |\alpha(x_2 + x_3)|, |\alpha(x_3 + x_1)|$}

= max{$|\alpha||x_1 + x_2|, |\alpha||x_2 + x_3|, |\alpha||x_3 + x_1|$}

But I don't know how to factor the $|\alpha|$ out of the max function.

Answer (score 1):

There’s really not much to it.

Let $z=\max\{kx,ky\}$, where $k\ge 0$. If $k=0$ this is clearly $0$, so $z=k\max\{x,y\}$. Suppose, then, that $k>0$. If $x\ge y$, then $kx\ge ky$, so $z=kx=k\max\{x,y\}$. If, on the other hand, $x<y$, then $z=ky=k\max\{x,y\}$. Thus, in all cases you can factor a non-negative multiplier out of the maximum. The number of terms is immaterial: I did it for two to keep the notation simple, but it works just as well with any number.